# how to write a kotlin file in java(generated) dir with specific package using AnnotationProcessor

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm using annotation processing to generate some code
and i need to create kotlin file in specific package
this is my code

```
@AutoService(Processor.class)
@IncrementalAnnotationProcessor(IncrementalAnnotationProcessorType.DYNAMIC)
@SuppressWarnings("NullAway")
public final class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
 
   @Override
   public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
     ....
   }

   private void writeKotlinFile(String pack, String fileName, String fileContent, Element it) {
     .....
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to use `OutputStream` like this in your `writeKolinFilee` function:

```java
private void writeKotlinFile(String pack, String fileName, String fileContent, Element it) {
    try {
        FileObject filerSourceFile = processingEnv.getFiler().createResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT,
            pack, fileName + ".kt", it);
        OutputStream outputStream = filerSourceFile.openOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```